# Converting Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy, and I ran the following code

```
C = np.random.random((10,2))
X = np.copy(C[:, 0])
Y = np.copy(C[:,1])
C[:, 0] = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
C[:,1] = np.arctan2(Y,X)
print(C)

X,Y = C[:,0], C[:,1]
R = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
T = np.arctan2(Y,X)
print(R)
print(T)
```

They are 2 different ways of transforming a 10x2 matrix of cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates. The first way was my answer, the second one is the correct one. They give different outputs, and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Modifying your source data is a very bad idea. To test this people will be forced to modify your script, to ensure the same `C` is used in both cases

Comment: `C[:, 0] = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
C[:,1] = np.arctan2(Y,X)` You have modified the value of C

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem. Once I fix the problem to ensure both scripts use the same data, I get the same results. The way this script is written *right now*, the second part is using the results of the first. It's trying to convert Polar to Polar

Answer (score 0):

You modified the column values of C in

```
C[:, 0] = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
C[:,1] = np.arctan2(Y,X)
```

Instead, do:

```
import numpy as np
C = np.random.random((10,2))
X = np.copy(C[:, 0])
Y = np.copy(C[:,1])
R = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
T = np.arctan2(Y,X)
print(R)
print(T)

X,Y = C[:,0], C[:,1]
R = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
T = np.arctan2(Y,X)
print(R)
print(T)
```